# calling Object Method gives "Uncaught TypeError: is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, function, typeerror

**Problem:**
Calling (`console.log(d.yakinlik.uzak.X1())`) this function

```
function Div(isim) {
    this.loc = document.getElementById(isim);
    this.getStyle = function (stili) {
        return window.getComputedStyle(this.loc).getPropertyValue(stili);
    };
    this.getIntStyle = function (stili) {
        return parseInt(this.getStyle(stili), 10);
    };
    this.yakinlik = {
        uzak: {
            X1: function () {
                return this.getIntStyle('left');
            }
        }
    };
}
```

gives

> Uncaught TypeError: this.getIntStyle is not a function

I have tried using:

```
    this.yakinlik = {
        uzak: {
        },
        orta: {
        },
        yakin: {
        },
        cokyakin: {
        }
    };
    this.yakinlik.uzak.X1 = function () { return this.getIntStyle('left'); };
```

but it failed too. But when I do not use a method here `this.yakinlik.uzak.X1 = function () { return this.getIntStyle('left'); };` like this `this.yakinlik.uzak.X1 = this.getIntStyle('left');` it works (actually it gives NaN, but it is normal because it hasn't recomputed, so I have to use a method there. ).

Here is the involved pieces of the code:

```
'use strict';
function Div(isim) {
    this.loc = document.getElementById(isim);
    this.getStyle = function (stili) {
        return window.getComputedStyle(this.loc).getPropertyValue(stili);
    };
    this.getIntStyle = function (stili) {
        return parseInt(this.getStyle(stili), 10);
    };
    this.yakinlik = {
        uzak: {
        },
        orta: {
        },
        yakin: {
        },
        cokyakin: {
        }
    };
    this.yakinlik.uzak.X1 = function () { return this.getIntStyle('left'); };
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}



var d = new Div("d");
d.loc.style.left = getRandomInt(0, window.innerWidth - 50) + "px";
d.loc.style.top = getRandomInt(0, window.innerHeight - 50) + "px";
console.log(d.yakinlik.uzak.X1() + " " + d.getIntStyle('top'));
```

How can I fix this without having to use a property there?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `d.yakinlik.uzak.X1()`, so inside `X1`, `this` will refer to the `uzak` object not the `Div` instance which does not have the `getIntStyle` property.

One solution is to use a closure variable like

```
function Div(isim) {
    this.loc = document.getElementById(isim);
    this.getStyle = function (stili) {
        return window.getComputedStyle(this.loc).getPropertyValue(stili);
    };
    this.getIntStyle = function (stili) {
        return parseInt(this.getStyle(stili), 10);
    };
    var div = this;
    this.yakinlik = {
        uzak: {
            X1: function () {
                return div.getIntStyle('left');
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k2hq7bb8/2/)

Comment: But, why does it work, when I use a property there instead of a method with `this`

Comment: @MindlessRanger sorry didn't get you

Comment: Using `this.getIntStyle('left');` under X1 doesn't give an error.

Comment: @MindlessRanger can you edit the above fiddle to recreate the issue

Comment: @MindlessRanger that is because in this case `this` is evaluated during the creation of the `Div` instance where `this` is still the object being created

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k2hq7bb8/5/ - this is the div, http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k2hq7bb8/6/ - see the log to see the value of `this` and `div`

Comment: Thanks, now I got it; this belongs to `uzak` in the fiddle which has method, but in the other fiddle this is processed before entering. Thanks.